# Dual of a complex lattice

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

We know that for a real full-ranked lattice $\Lambda$, with real square matrix $\mathbf{B}$, the dual lattice $\Lambda^{\vee}$ has matrix $(\mathbf{B}^{-1})^T$.

Now If we have a complex lattice with $N \times N$ complex matrix $\mathbf{C}$, what would be the matrix of its dual lattice? Would it be the same? Or we need to put complex conjugation?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure about your formula: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse206A-a/LecDual.pdf

Comment: The formula works in the case that $B$ is full-rank, as $D = B(B^t B)^{-1} = BB^{-1} B^{-t} = B^{-t}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $G=\{a+ib:a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be the Gaussian integers (something similar can be done with the Eisentstein integers defined via third complex roots of unity as well).

$G$ is the ring of integers of the complex field $\mathbb{C}$. With the inner product of $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$ defined via the hermitian inner product
$$
x\cdot \overline{y}=x_1 \overline{y_1}+\cdots+x_n\overline{y_n},
$$
the dual lattice of a lattice $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is defined as
$$
\Lambda^{\ast}=\{x \in \mathbb{C}^n: x \cdot \overline{u} \in G~for~all~ u \in \Lambda\}.
$$
The lattice $\Lambda$ itself is of course the set of all vectors
$$
\xi M,
$$
where $\xi=(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n) \in G^n$ is arbitrary and $M$ is a complex $n\times m$ generating matrix for $\Lambda.$

Comment: This formula for the dual works if the lattice is full rank; otherwise, one needs to restrict it to the span of the lattice.